# Adding an auto-incrementing UserID field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am creating an API to get and post values from a Database using the MEAN stack.

I want to automatically generate the userID starting from 0 when each entry is created in the usesrschema.

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    //userId: Number,
    username: String,
    password: String, //hash created from password
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
})
```

How is it that I add a userID starting from 0 and autoincrementing with each insertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of choices in the NPM to make life easier on yourself.

[mongodb-autoincrement](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-autoincrement)

[mongoose-auto-increment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment) - specifically for using with Mongoose

The list can go on and on, (as there are quite a few libraries to accomplish this), my suggestion would be to try the [mongoose-auto-increment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment) which is pretty much what you are looking for.